Spring boot Datasource creation issue in Multitenancy
We are basically trying to acheive password change without restart of service as defined in https://blog.jdriven.com/2021/06/configure-hikari-connection-pool-when-using-rds-iam/
Implemented the class as shown below in the snippe.
I have to call the CustomDatasource with new keyword as we have to create new connection for every tenant as its Multitenant enabled service
serviceA bean is null in getPassword() method in CustomDatasource
@Service
public class CustomDatasource extends HikariDataSource {

    @Autowired
    private ServiceA serviceA;

    @Autowired
    public CustomDatasource(HikariConfig hikariConfig) {
        super(hikariConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        serviceA.someMethod();
    }

}

-------------------------------------------------------------------------
@Service
public class HikariDataSourceBuilder {

    CacheStore.getCache().setDataSource(new CustomDatasource(getHikariConfig(tenantId));

    public HikariConfig getHikariConfig(String tenant) {
        return hikariConfig;
    }
}

--------------------------------------------------------------------------

@Service
public class ServiceA {

    public String someMethod() {
        return "";
    }
}

Options tried

Made CustomDatasource as @Scope(scopeName =
ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE), so that everytime new
instance of the class is returned, and made changes to get the bean
from Application context in HikariDataSourceBuilder.java class.
Tried few other options by defining Postcontruct in
CustomDatasource and also by changing the way ServiceA set in
CustomDatasource

